# Extracting/Separate records with duplicate and unique values from File Python

Tags: python-3.x, duplicates, text-extraction

I have one input file with following values:

```
file1.txt

Name       ID    Code
ABC        12    322
QWE        97    214
ASD        86    111
FGH        12    322
RTY        86    322
BNM        86    214
POK        12    111
MKI        33    322
```

I want to generate multiple files based on duplication of `ID`. When above file will be given as input then output will be:

First File

```
12.txt
ABC        12    322
FGH        12    322
POK        12    111
```

Second File

```
97.txt
QWE        97    214
```

Third File

```
86.txt
ASD        86    111
RTY        86    322
BNM        86    214
```

Fourth File

```
33.txt
MKI        33    322
```

All the records with same IDs will be stored in one and if there is no duplicate just store in another file. Filename should be `ID.txt`.

`.txt File` as input is mendatory and in txt file there are character wise as there is some value of each space.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this, by using [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) and [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter).
First, you have to iterate over your data and add lines to the corresponding set based on the `ID`. I recommend using a `DictReader` and a `defaultdict` (use the ID as key) to simplify your code. If you have stored all your rows into a `dict`, you can write the data into separate files.

Something like the following should do:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

# store all rows as a `list` indexed by the ID
data = defaultdict(list)

with open('file.csv') as fh:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fh, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in reader:
        data[row['id']].append(row)

# Write rows to different files based on the ID
for id_, rows in data.items():
    fieldnames = rows[0].keys()
    with open(f'{id_}.txt', 'w') as fh:
        writer = csv.DicWriter(fh, delimiter=' ', fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: Constraint is that, it only accepts .txt file and in text file we have to search character by character as there are spaces in .txt file. multiple spaces in that file

Comment: That's fine. You actually have a "csv" - But instead of having a comma as a delimiter, you are using spaces. I added `skipinitialspace=True` so it can handle multiple spaces between each column. Hence you can just use `12.txt` as input for the `open()` function.

Comment: I tested the script and it handles your input just fine. But the output differs slightly from your expected result as each column is only separated by one whitespace. You could simply adopt the last 3 line of my script and make use of [rjust](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust) or [ljust](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust).